# Tomcat JDBCRealm using Oracle database over SSL (PROTOCOL=TCPS)

Tags: oracle, tomcat, ssl, jdbcrealm

I'm trying to implement JDBCRealm in tomcat (as described in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/realm-howto.html#Configuring%20a%20Realm) to check credential agains Oracle Database. The thing is that I want database to communicate over SSL. So I configured listener to use TCPS. Like that:

```
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=1521)))<br>
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=<hostname>)(PORT=1512)))
```

Generated certificates, etc. I have no problem connecting to database using tcps from sqlplus or from WLS (I can use connection property `oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites=(SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)` there without any problem).

However, I cant get JDBCRealm to work with the database over TCPS. If I configure realm like this:
`<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" debug="99" driverName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = <hostname>)(PORT = 1512)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = <service name>)))" connectionName="<login>" connectionPassword="<password>" userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass" userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" />`
I'm getting following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I imported certificates in JKS store which I configured in Tomcat like this:

With no success.

I'm not a professional in Tomcat (more in databases). I'll appreciate any help or pointing me in right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error seems to indicate that SSL certificate is not trusted.

I suggest to verify that you indeed have certificate in your trust store (there is a command line tool in JDK to list trust store content, you can Google it) and then add following parameter in Tomcat startup script:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to trust store>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a big leap for me :) Now I'm having following errors: `java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize ssl context. oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unable to initialize the trust store. java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect  java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed` But password for trustore is correct in catalina.sh `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to jks> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<pass>`

Comment: It helped a lot! Just needed to add javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<pass> Mistakenly added keyStore in previous post. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, the other thing bothering me is the password visible in process list. Tried putting it to -Doptionsfile=<file with trust parameters> without success. Looks like Tomcat doesn't recognize it?